# ansible_env variables missing between calls

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

TLDR;
I couldn't figure out why a command in my playbook kept being skipped no matter what computer I was running it on...  turns out a variable that shows in ansible_env when I run it on the command line does not appear usable for the playbook...  How can I use this missing fact??

I'm using ansible to configure my personal linux desktops and laptops (on which I usually install very similar things), but want to install certain things when I'm using Gnome desktop vs a Mate desktop.   ( I use both Ubuntu-Mate and Ubuntu, and when I am installing on Ubuntu, I want some of the Gnome apps to be installed (gnome-tweaks, shell-extension-prefs, etc))

So when I was looking for facts I could use in a when, I ran `ansible -m setup localhost`, inside of ansible_env I found:

```
   "ansible_env": {
        "COLORTERM": "truecolor",
        "COMPIZ_CONFIG_PROFILE": "mate",
        "DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS": "unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus",
        "DESKTOP_AUTOSTART_ID": "10fbd59767277bef2f160865055738627400000121410000",
        "DESKTOP_SESSION": "mate",
        "DISPLAY": ":0",
        "GDMSESSION": "mate",
        ...
```

and when I ran the same command against Ubuntu, DESKTOP_SESSION returned 'gnome'...

and to clarify, I ran the fact gathering on each of the individual machines to make sure I was getting the DESKTOP_SESSION on all of them...

but when I used `when: lookup('env','DESKTOP_SESSION') == "gnome"` no matter which computer I ran it on, it skipped this task...

So I ran

```
- name: Debug all env vars
  debug:
    var: ansible_facts
```

that DESKTOP_SESSION fact is not in the list (which would explain why it's being skipped) - my question is why is it missing, and how can I get it to be used (or is there another way to determine my desktop environment on Linux?)

I figured someone might ask, so here is my local.yml playbook with the when clause in it:

```
- hosts: localhost
  become: true
#  var_files:
#    - config.yml
  tasks:
    # setup normal home directories
    - include: tasks/system/directories.yml

    # update entire system
    - include: tasks/system/update-system.yml

    # sudoers file
    - include: tasks/sudo/sudoers.yml

    # base system packages
    - include: tasks/software/system.yml

    # prep git access
    - include: tasks/system/copy-files.yml
    - include: tasks/system/git-links.yml
    - include: tasks/software/git-repos.yml

    # mount nfs drives to freenas & home folder links
    - include: tasks/system/nfs-mounts.yml
    - include: tasks/system/sym-links.yml

    # install various applications
    - include: tasks/software/accessories.yml    
    - include: tasks/software/development.yml
    - include: tasks/software/games.yml
    - include: tasks/software/graphics.yml
    - include: tasks/software/internet.yml
    - include: tasks/software/multimedia.yml
    - include: tasks/software/office.yml

    # gnome followups
    - include: tasks/software/gnome-followup.yml
      when: lookup('env','DESKTOP_SESSION') == "gnome"

    # laptop tools
    - include: tasks/system/laptops.yml
      when: ansible_nodename == "the-tardis" or ansible_nodename == "satelite-5"
```

and this is the command I use to run ansible (from a bootstrap script)...

`sudo ansible-playbook --vault-password-file ~/.ansible_vault_key ./local.yml --connection=local;`

[edited for clarification on running on my personal machines and adding the command that runs ansible]

Comment: `lookup` always run locally on the controller. So used with `env`, it only returns environment variables on your local host never on the target. Moreover, the vars your are referring to are (from memory) only set when you are running an interactive session in the given desktop environment. So there are very little chances you can find them while connecting over ssh to a remote target (connecting to localhost uses the local connection). Moreover, it is totally possible to have gnome AND mate installed on the same machine. You're best solution IMO is to check which packages are installed.

Comment: @Zeitounator - this is not the case... I'll edit the question to reflect this - but I'm using ansible to administer my personal systems (currently 1 desktop and 2 laptops) and as such, I've run the `ansible -m setup localhost` on the laptop that i'm running ansible on to verify that DESKTOP_SESSION is in the list variables it returns, and that it was indeed Gnome.

Comment: Your problem is `sudo` which turns to root before launching ansible which is not logued in an interactive session. This is exactly the same case as connecting remotely for this particular concern. Just run `ansible -m setup localhost -a filter=ansible_env` and do it again with `sudo` in front and you'll see by yourself.

Comment: So is there a way to pull that desktop session variable in somehow so that I can use that?  Or run ansible-playbook without the sudo?

Comment: Don't sudo your ansible command and use privilege escalation in your playbook where needed.